# Remove everything between pairs of braces with sed

Tags: regex, sed

I've got a string that looks like this:

```
[%{%B%F{blue}%}master %{%F{red}%}*%{%f%k%b%}%{%f%k%b%K{black}%B%F{green}%}]
```

I want to remove the substrings matching `%{...}`, which may or may not contain further substrings of the same order.

I should get: `[master *]` as the final output. My progress so far:

```
gsed -E 's/%\{[^\}]*\}//g'
```

which gives:

```
echo '[%{%B%F{blue}%}master %{%F{red}%}*%{%f%k%b%}%{%f%k%b%K{black}%B%F{green}%}]' | gsed -E 's/%\{[^\}]*\}//g'
[%}master %}*%B%F{green}%}]
```

So, this works fine for `%{...}` sections which do *not* contain `%{...}`. It fails for strings like `%{%B%F{blue}%}` (it returns `%}`).

What I want to do is parse the string until I find the *matching* `}`, then remove everything up to that point, rather than removing everything between `%{` and the *first* `}` I encounter. I'm not sure how to do this.

I'm fully aware that there are probably multiple ways to do this; I'd prefer an answer regarding the way specified in the question if it is possible, but any ideas are more than welcome.

Comment: Regular expressions are not good a choice for matching nested parentheses. Nested parentheses do not form a regular language.

Comment: You actually can't use regex to match nested brackets, you can match upto a finite number with an ever longer regex but you can't match an arbitary number.  I wrote a code generator once to match up to 9 levels of nesting, it was the largest regex you ever saw and it wasn't terribly performant.

Comment: +1 for sample input, expected output and actual code in use. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
echo '[%{%B%F{blue}%}master %{%F{red}%}*%{%f%k%b%}%{%f%k%b%K{black}%B%F{green}%}]' |
sed 's/%{/{/g;:a;s/{[^{}]*}//g;ta'
[master *]
```

Comment: That works a charm. If it's not too much trouble, could you give an explanation of how it works?

Comment: Firstly replace all `%{` with `{`, then delete all inner `{...}` and if successful repeat till no more.

Answer (score 0):

Use recursion to eat it out from the inside out.

```
s/%{.*?%}//g
```

Then wrap in

```
while(there's at least one more brace)
```

(probably while $? -ne 0 ...  whatever rcode sed uses to say "no matches!")

Comment: I think this does not work, because the terminating pattern is a lone `}`, not `%}`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -E 's/%{([^{}]*({[^}]*})*[^{}]*)*}//g'
```